# How to fix/dock window that was dragged out?

Tags: intellij-idea

I accidentally dragged the Run window out of the fixed position and now I can't seem to re-fix it.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-modes.html#windowed) help?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the gear icon on the left side of the window and uncheck the 'Floating mode'.